I want to add requests from an Android App as a Whitelist in my backend
I have created an android app that I want to add to the Play Store. It should communicate with a separate Typescript backend.
For security reasons, I have added a CORS whitelist. Usually I would just add origins to the whitelist, say facebook.com, but for the app I have no idea how I would get that.
I want to send GET and POST requests to this hosted backend.
I have tried to search for this issue but I just keep getting confused with jargon. I am new to this, and this app has been built with Ionic. I have built apps with Node.js before but never a mobile app.

You shouldn't be relying on CORS for security. CORS only matters for browsers - Android apps will bypass CORS completely (unless the app is a web browser).
Your best bet would be to require an API key on your server and then include that key in your app's source code. You won't be able to completely hide this key, but it's better than leaving it completely open.

Using a hardcoded key is completely insecure and will be discovered in under 5 minutes from anyone actually attacking his service.  Instead, he should use authentication outside the app-  a password or other shared secret input by the user and known by the server to ensure the user is authorized.

KISS - of course adding authentication would be more secure, but not every app should require a user to sign up. Depends on OP's requirements, of course.

KISS only applies if the simple solution actually works.  Yours doesn't.  Its inherently insecure.  If their API is serving public data and can be safely allowed to be access, the KISS solution is not to put any security on it.  If it can't, then you need a REAL solution, not a hack that doesn't even put up a decent speed bump but gives you a false sense of security.  I'd fire an engineer for suggesting this.

More secure than CORS :)
